# Is there asymptotic expansion of heat kernel of complex laplacian?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, dg.differential-geometry

On real Riemannian manifold , the heat kernel of the laplacian have an asymptotic expansion . But on complex manifold , i haven't seen a result like this , i.e. the heat kernel of the Kodaira Laplacian have an asymptotic expansion as the real case . Maybe I know so little , so I want to ask that Is there an asymptotic expansion of the heat kernel of the Kodaira laplacian ?

Comment: Have you looked at "Holomorphic Morse Inequalities and Bergman Kernels" by Ma and Marinescu?  I just saw the introduction, but it looks like it might have something similar to what you want.